# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError use only params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm getting `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in MicropostsController#create` on line #2 in the create action.

Tried also changing `f.hidden_field` to `hidden_field_tag` but still getting `ForbiddenAttributesError`

micropost_controller

```
  def create
    tag = Tag.find(params[:micropost][:tag_id])
    @micropost = tag.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    @micropost.user_id = current_user.id
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Posted!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

tags_controller

```
  def details
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @tag.microposts
    @micropost = @tag.microposts.build if sign_in?
  end
```

micropost form

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @micropost %>
  <div class="field">
    <%=  f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Your post" %>
    <%=  f.hidden_field :tag_id %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

in tags.rb

```
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
```

in microposts.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to delete `tag_id` from your `microposts` parameters:

```
tag = Tag.find(params[:micropost].delete(:tag_id))
@micropost = tag.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
```

If that won't fix it, just whit-list the params (it's good idea anyway):

```
micropost_params = params.require(:micropost).permit(:name, :title, ...)
@micropost = tag.microposts.build(micropost_params)
```

Comment: `micropost_params = params.require(:micropost).permit(:content,:tag_id,:user_id)` isn't helping..

Answer (score 0):

this

```
def create
  tag = Tag.find(params[:micropost][:tag_id])
  #...
end
```

should probably be changed to this

```
def create
  tag = Tag.find(params[:tag_id])
  #...
end
```

Comment: If I change `f.hidden_field` to `hidden_field_tag` than you are correct but still the second line won't work. In both cases the second line through the error I wrote.